# Проблемма с установкой пакета через npm

Tags: npm

Выдает такую ошибку при вводе в консоль команды npm i styled-components
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2023-05-12T06_30_43_357Z-debug-0.log
что делать?